# Проверка на уникальность JAVA mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Стоит уникальный ключ на email и , когда я в форму jtext ввожу эмайл , который уже есть в базе , то программа крашается,типо пишет , что в базе уже есть такой и второго такого не может быть . ЭТО понятно всё , что он не должен добавляться, но можно ли это как то сделать , чтоб программа  не крашалась , а просто выводило на экран сообщение "такой эмаил уже есть". Я себе это представляю как ввести всё в массив , пройтись по массиву и если есть то вывод сообщения на экран , но можно ли это как то легче сделать? JAVA. 
Hе знаю там 
String query="Select *From `info` WHERE email="+email;
if(!query) true else false 
ну что то типа этого можно замутить,а то , если записывать в массив и тд , то зачем тогда primary key на это ставить , если он и так и так скажет, что не подходит , так как уже существует  ? подскажите , пожалуйста, можно ли как то по другому замутить ?

Comment: Делайте запросом.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean hasEmail(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException {
    String email = "email@gmail.com";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE email= ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs.next();
}
```

Comment: public boolean hasEmail()   {
  try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Users?serverTimezone=Europe/Tallin&useSSL=false","root","");
 st=con.createStatement();
String emaill = "emaggil@gmail.com";
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE email=emaill";
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement =con.prepareStatement(sql);
 preparedStatement.setString(1, emaill);
 ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs.next();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
}   
}

Comment: Сделал так, но там всегда false и ещё такой if if (!a.hasEmail()){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"err");
        }else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"OK");
    }                    
он всегда err выдает и еще ругается java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: сделал все , спасибо за функцию

Comment: Отметьте плз ответ как правильный